# Why is principal Trig solution a negative angle

Tags: trigonometry

This may be because of the way the computer system is set up where I have to input the answers to my homework questions ... but it still puzzles me. I am fairly sure that the principal solutions of trigonometric equations are found on the interval from $0$ to $\pi$. However, for a simple equation like $\sin x = -1/2$, I get from the system that either one of the answers $7\pi/6$ or $11\pi/6$ is wrong. Instead, the system demands the answer $-\pi/6$, which is coterminal with $11\pi/6$ but is outside the interval from $0$ to $2\pi$. Does anyone know why that is the correct answer? I am puzzled.

Comment: There are two intervals which the principal solution is usually taken. $(-\pi,\pi]$ and $[0, 2\pi)$. The computer uses the first.

Comment: @Shuri2060: While you're correct about the two possibilities, I don't think that's the cause, as $-\frac{5\pi}6$ also lies in that interval. See my answer.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arcsine function is a partial inverse function of the sine function. It can only be a partial inverse because the sine function is periodic. In particular, the sine function (on the reals) obtains all of its values exactly once in the interval $\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right],$ and the arcsine function is the inverse of the restriction of the sine function to this interval. This is why the arcsine of $-\frac12$ is $-\frac\pi6,$ rather than some other number.

I suspect that the computer is set up so that answers must be arcsine values.

Comment: Ok this clears that. However this does mean that there is some duality in how one obtains solutions to trigonometric equations. Your answer clears the main issue (and explains why a calculator chooses certain values over others) ... but then either on the interval from 0 to 2Pi or for obtaining the general solution, one cannot possibly use the inverse trigonometric functions. Is there a special name for the set of solutions that ARE based on the inverse functions?

Comment: They don't have a particular name, to my knowledge. Now, one can start with such a value, then use other properties of trigonometric functions to get the rest. For instance, one can use symmetry in the unit circle to obtain that $-\frac{5\pi}6$ is a solution, as well--and indeed, the only other solution in the interval $(-\pi,\pi]$--then use periodicity to obtain solutions in any given specified interval, or a general form for all solutions.